# how to query two tables , some items in table 1 do not an association with table2 ?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

my database schema is below, each id from email table is associated with an id from attachment table, some do not. for example id 1 from email table have attachment(s) from attachments table (3 entries of id 1 for example), while id 2 from email does not have an id2 in  attachments. I tried to query the result using the following, but only attachments field showed. In essence, I want the result to show everything from date x to date y, whether it has an attachment or not.

```
SELECT CONCAT(email.from_fld , date_fld) AS name, email.body_fld, attachments.attach_fld 
FROM email 
INNER JOIN attachments 
ON email.id = attachments.id
WHERE date_fld >= "2012-01-01 00:00:00" AND date_fld <= "2013-01-01 23:59:59" ORDER BY date_fld ASC;
```

This is my database Schema

```
email table
    id      INT
    from_fld    VARCHAR
    to_fld  VARCHAR
    subj_fld    MEDIUMTEXT
    date_fld    DATETIME
    mailbox VARCHAR
    mailto  VARCHAR
    body_fld    LONGTEXT
    numAttach   INT
    attachNames MEDIUMTEXT
    attachText  MEDIUMTEXT
    headings    MEDIUMTEXT

attachments table
    id          INT
    type_fld        VARCHAR
    filename_fld    VARCHAR
    encode_fld  INT
    attach_fld      LONGBLOB

origemail table
    id      INT
    orig_fld    LONGBLOB

tags table
    id          INT
    cat_fld     VARCHAR
    key_fld     VARCHAR
    priority_fld    INT
    notes_fld       MEDIUMTEXT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join` if you want everything in the *first* table in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT CONCAT(e.from_fld , e.date_fld) AS name, e.body_fld, a.attach_fld 
FROM email e LEFT JOIN
     attachments a
     ON e.id = a.id
WHERE e.date_fld >= '2012-01-01' AND
      e.date_fld < '2013-01-02' 
ORDER BY date_fld ASC;
```

Notice the other changes:

- I introduced table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and read.
- I qualified *all* column names, so it is clear where the columns come form.
- I use the ANSI standard delimiter for string and date constants (a single quote rather than a double quote).
- I simplified the date comparisons.

Comment: perfect answer, you are the champ!

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'full join' instead of inner join

Comment: MySQL does not support full joins.